# Is there a limit to the amount of low quality answers an account can give?

Tags: support, answers, post-ban

I've noticed an account which gives low quality answers to numerous questions (1-liners that should be comments).  If these are flagged and removed, is there any deterrent to keep that account from continuing to post low-quality answers to other questions?

Comment: You are aware there is post-ban mechanism, where if a user's contributions are badly received they are in danger of being either question or answer banned, right?

Comment: @yivi I don't know anything about it so I guess I'm looking for specifics on whether badly received contributions include those that are flagged, downvoted, or both?

Comment: I am afraid that the algorithm is secret. But I think score and status (for questions, closed/open; for answers deleted as NAA) are the most important parameters.

Comment: You can get some information [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th), which is the canonical for users that find themselves post banned.

Comment: Mind you, in my experience it doesn't appear to put users above certain reputation threshold (1k or 2k?) in danger. This is just my observation, so I could be wrong.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/answer-bans

Comment: I believe a down vote is a strong signal to the algorithm and that is in effect immediately. If you have to wait for a low quality flag to be processed it might take a while with a slight possibility reviewers find that answer awesome. So if anything, down vote first, then check the remaining options you have (flag, delete) and if the answer is on a low quality question, (close/down) vote the question as well. For a continuing flood of low-quality stuff, you might raise a custom mod flag so a mod can check if the account has a history of bad content and then take extra steps.

Comment: I noticed a similar pattern. 1. Read the highest upvoted comment under the question itself. 2. Post as answer. 3. Profit. They do not realize such a comment alone *does not answer the question*. There is no appropriate flag, it's just another Bad Answer.